# Export the result to CSV Azure PowerShell Warnign Sign

Tags: csv, powershell, azure

I am assuming this warning is causing problem.

> WARNING: GeoReplicationEnabled property will be deprecated in a future
>   release of Azure PowerShell. The value will be merged into the
>   AccountType property

because when I did this command

```
Get-AzureWebsite | export-csv -Path "C:\Users\km\Desktop\AzureProject\Hello Pay-As-You-Go-Website.csv"
```

my CSV file is totally fine

SO the problem I am having is

When I execute this command

```
Get-AzureStorageAccount | Format-Table -Property StorageAccountName, Location, AccountType, StorageAccountStatus
```

The result is like this

> StorageAccountName         Location          AccountType
>   StorageAccountStatus
>   ---------------------      ---------         ------------   --------------------       HelloSushi                  East US          Standard_GRS      Created
>
> WARNING: GeoReplicationEnabled property will be deprecated in a future
>   release of Azure PowerShell. The value will be merged into the
>   AccountType property.

and I add this code to move this result to CSV like this

```
Get-AzureStorageAccount | Format-Table -Property StorageAccountName, Location, AccountType, StorageAccountStatus | export-csv -Path "C:\Users\km\Desktop\AzureProject\Susco Pay-As-You-Go-Storage.csv"
```

but I checked on CSV.file, it is totally does not make sense. it is not same one.

so ,

I would like to show the result exactly on CSV like when I did this code

```
Get-AzureStorageAccount | Format-Table -Property StorageAccountName, Location, AccountType, StorageAccountStatus
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `Format-Table` is what causes it to all come out in one column. Try this instead: `Get-AzureStorageAccount | Select-Object -Property StorageAccountName, Location, AccountType, StorageAccountStatus | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\km\Desktop\AzureProject\Hello Pay-As-You-Go-Website.csv"` In general, using `Select-Object` is preferred if you intend to pass the results to any other commands that manipulate the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Out-File instead of Export-CSV it is giving the exact same output as console

==

You can't do a Format-List to Export-Csv, [this link explains it](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/why-cant-i-pipe-format-table-export-csv).

Comment: It works but it was not exactly like when I did Get-AzureSubscription, All information was in all same column. Do you know other methods?

Comment: You can't do a export-csv to format-list, this link explains it http://windowsitpro.com/blog/why-cant-i-pipe-format-table-export-csv

Comment: I think I found the solution about my question.